# Store hig-res picture offline in Android

Tags: java, android, database, image, sqlite

I'm developing an Android application but I need some help.
I need to store about 2000 image in high resolution (1024x768 and about 2.5 MB each) and the application must work offline so i can't retrieve them from an online database or from anywhere else. These picture should be stored in the SQLite db inside the application because each one of them are related to a specific product.

I've tried to convert the picture to a Base64 string but the result is too big and the app crash. It works only if it's about 467x300 and 30 KB but it loose all its quality so this is not a good solution.

Hope you have helpful suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: "These picture should be stored in the SQLite db inside the application because each one of them are related to a specific product" -- or, store them in a file, and put the filename in the database. Or, store them in a file whose filename can be derived by other data. Personally, I wouldn't put images in a database. That being said, why Base64? SQLite supports BLOB columns.

Answer (score 1):

The way this problem is typically solved is to not store the images in the database, but rather store a link to them in the database. If you want them to be private, store them in the private app storage location. Getting images from a database is tricky, and editing binary blobs like that can be tricky. It can cause issues in the database, which might cause things to be slower. Also, it's easier to load images from a file than from a database.

Also, you could use BLOB, which allows for storing binary data. SQLite supports that, so...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to handle my high resolution images:

1. give a unique image id to the image, stored in the database
2. save the image in the android storage
3. whenever I need a high res image, get its name from the database. use the name to look up the image from storage.

I'm happy to provide a code example, just let me know.